# Does an additional parameter to a objective function always guarantee the better or equal optimization result?

Tags: optimization, dimension-theory-analysis, parameter-estimation

As the title, this seems to be intuitively correct. So, I am looking for some relevant theorem on this. In other words, 'Higher parameter space in some optimization problem gives the more optimal value than the original parameter space.

Comment: Broadly, this follows from the fact that if $A \subset B$ then $\sup_{x \in A} f(x) \le \sup_{x\in B} f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks!  By the way,  Do you know any theoerm or some material? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not aware of any results that deal with the subject matter explicitly, it probably falls into the fairly well known category.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Good day.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an *additional* parameter, then the new problem embeds the other one, which guarantees that the optimum cannot is at least as good. Of course, adding a parameter does not guarantee that the optimum will be (strictly) better.